# spring jdbctemplate with insert or update query with oracle db

Tags: spring, oracle11g, jdbctemplate

I am using spring jdbc template for batch inserts but recently we have requirement to also to batch updated. Question I have is, is it possible in spring jdbctemplate that if record present in db then it does update else does batch inserts?

If so then sample or docs would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not to check if the PK of the object? If the PK is > 0 than it's an update, otherwise an insert

Comment: That is what I am doing but Its seperate query for me and based on that output i do batchupdate or batchinsert. Wanted to see if there is a better way to do that or not. What i mean is , if there is a way in jdbctemplate where you provide list of entities and it does check before either inserting or updatting.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such method (like in hibernate)